# Regex with negative lookahead across multiple lines

Tags: regex, parsing, regex-lookarounds

For the past few hours I've been trying to match address(es) from the following sample data and I can't get it to work:

```
medicalHistory      None
address             24 Lewin Street, KUBURA, 
                NSW, Australia
email               MaryBeor@spambob.com


address             16 Yarra Street, 
                                     LAWRENCE, VIC, Australia
name                Mary   Beor
medicalHistory      None
phone               00000000000000000000353336907
birthday            26-11-1972
```

My plan was to find anything that starts with "address", is followed by any space followed by characters, numbers commas and newlines and ends with newline followed by a character. I came up with the following (and many variations of it):

```
address\s+([0-9a-zA-Z, \n\t]+)(?!\n\w)
```

Unfortunately that matches the following:

```
address             24 Lewin Street, KUBURA,
                NSW, Australia
email               MaryBeor
```

and

```
address             16 Yarra Street,
                                 LAWRENCE, VIC, Australia
name                Mary   Beor
medicalHistory      None
phone               00000000000000000000353336907
birthday            26
```

instead of

```
address             24 Lewin Street, KUBURA, 
                NSW, Australia
```

and

```
address             16 Yarra Street,
                                 LAWRENCE, VIC, Australia
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
address\s+((?![\r\n]+\w)[0-9a-zA-Z, \r\n\t])+
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?36f00).

This `((?![\r\n]+\w)[0-9a-zA-Z, \r\n\t])+` is the important part, where I say, match the next character from `[0-9a-zA-Z, \r\n\t]`, if `(?![\r\n]+\w)` is not following. This is matching what you expect.

In both your cases the regex stopped matching because of a character that is not included in your character class. If you want to go that way than you would need to combine a [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) and a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
address\s+([0-9a-zA-Z, \n\r\t]+?)(?=\r\w)
```

`[0-9a-zA-Z, \n\r\t]+?` is matching as less as possible till the condition `(?=\r\w)` is true.

See it [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com?36f09)

Comment: @n1te Perhaps the greedy quantifier `+`, which consumes everything till the `@`, and still satisfy the negative look-ahead.

Comment: @n1te I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: @stema strange the second solution doesn't seem to work when I run it through preg_match but it works in Regexr

Comment: @n1te, I guess this is because I used only `\r` as newline character, since regexr has it. replace `\r` with `\n` or with `[\r\n]+` as I did in the first solution.

Comment: both links gives no match

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your regex is that `+` is greedy and goes until it finds a character out of that group, the `@` in the first case and `-` in the second.

Another approach is to use a non-greedy quantifier and a positive look-ahead for a newline followed by a word-character, like ([python](/questions/tagged/python) version):

```
re.findall(r'address\s+.*?(?=\n\w)', s, re.DOTALL)
```

It yields:

```
['address             24 Lewin Street, KUBURA, \n                NSW, Australia',
 'address             16 Yarra Street, \n                                     LAWRENCE, VIC, Australia']
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have to run your code to understand it better. Thanks for your help