# Remove selected character delimited paragraphs using an inverted negative lookahead across multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-negation

I have this `input string`:

```
string = '''p1 = {
s,
},

p2 = {
{s,
},

p3 = {
s,
},

p2 = {
}s,
},'''
```

I am trying to replace all paragraphs starting with `p2 = {` and ending with `},` and end up with this new expected `output string`:

```
p1 = {
s,
},

p3 = {
s,
},
```

I can achieve this without using a regex by just looping over the lines. But how would I do it with a regex?

This method using [re.subn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn) does not make any replacement and I don't understand why not:

```
import re
repl = ''
pattern = r'p2 = {.*?},'
new_string, number_of_subs_made = re.subn(pattern, repl, string, 
re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
```

This method using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) seems to be able to find all matches:

```
import re
pattern = r'.*?(p2 = {.*?},).*?'
m = re.findall(pattern, string, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
print('\n'.join(m))
```

It prints this output:

```
p2 = {
{s,
},
p2 = {
}s,
},
```

There is a question on how to emulate `grep -v` and exclude lines with pattern matches, and the answer suggests using a negative lookahead: [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230)

And there is a question on how to use negative lookahead across multiple lines here:
[Regex with negative lookahead across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979990)

Would it perhaps be possible to somehow invert that negative lookahead and print the lines that do not match?

Comment: You should use `re.subn(pattern, repl, string, 
flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)` or `re.subn(pattern, repl, string, 0, 
re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)`. Also, the pattern might be made a bit safer with anchors: `pattern = r'^p2 = {.*?},$'`.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. I ended up with this `new_string, number_of_subs_made = re.subn(re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL), repl, string)` once I looked at the question, which this was marked as a duplicate of. I hadn't noticed the `count` going before the `flags`. Thanks.