# geting string from tags using sed and grep

Tags: regex, xml, sed, grep

**UPDATE 2** 
i think i need something simple as this :
[Regex with negative lookahead across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979990/regex-with-negative-lookahead-across-multiple-lines)

getting the first  where it is not precedes by parent 
i have tried this without success

```
((?<![<parent>]))<version>.*
```

or this but still it capture all the version's :

```
(?<!^<parent>)<version>(?!<\/parent>)
```

how to get string from tags using sed and grep 
i try to capture the tags :
 `<groupId>org.test.proj.assent</groupId>
        <artifactId>mainapp</artifactId>
        <version>mainapp.1.4</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <name>main app 1</name>`

and then from there i guess i will extract the string :

```
<version>mainapp.1.4</version>
```

i tried this :

```
sed -n '/version/,/version/p' pom.xml | grep -o -e '<version>.*'
```

but it gives me all the versions

also i try to capture :

```
sed -n '/\/artifactId/,/\/version/p' pom.xml | grep -o -e '<version>.*'
```

but all file is printed

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" >
    <modelVersion>55.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.test.proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-invoker</artifactId>
        <version>invoker.0.4</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.test.proj.assent</groupId>
    <artifactId>mainapp</artifactId>
    <version>mainapp.1.4</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>main app 1</name>

    <properties>
        <app-name>Testing App</app-name>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.prod.db</groupId>
                <artifactId>srver-db</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    </project>
```

i can use only native linux tools no installs

**UPDATED xml and String to capture**

Comment: Can you use a dedicated [XML parsing tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash)? `sed` and `grep` are not XML syntax aware.

Comment: no i can't pure linux tools

Comment: yes the standard AWS linux

Comment: @user63898 can you add sample input and show exact string required as output? there are multiple `<version>` tags, on what basis do you need to select as output? is it the string `this one i need` or something else? also, can this tag be across multiple lines?

Comment: can't give real example 
but yes other <version> have parents and string can be any thing

Comment: still not clear to me, exact `parent` tag or `foo` and `foo2` are also parent tags here?

Comment: libxslt or libxml2 may be installed or available: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2018-03-packages/ then you can try things like: https://superuser.com/questions/266641/is-there-a-native-tool-for-parsing-xml-files-available-on-redhat

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Do not use regular expressions to parse XML. Or at least, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags so you know what you are doing.

Comment: im not going to read all this..but this case is very specific  not to general or big
just looking for fast way to get the job done

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk '/<project/{next} !s && match($0, /<([a-zA-Z]+)>/, tag){s=1} s && ($0~ "</" tag[1] ">"){s=0} !s && match($0, "<version>([^<]*)</version>", ver) {print ver[1]}' file
mainapp.1.4

$ awk '/<project/{next} !s && match($0, /<([a-zA-Z]+)>/, tag){s=1} s && ($0~ "</" tag[1] ">"){s=0} !s && match($0, "<version>([^<]*)</version>", ver) {print ver[0]}' file
<version>mainapp.1.4</version>
```

Put in several lines for readability:

```
awk '/<project/{next} 
    !s && match($0, /<([a-zA-Z]+)>/, tag){s=1} 
    s && ($0~ "</" tag[1] ">"){s=0} 
    !s && match($0, "<version>([^<]*)</version>", ver) {print ver[1]}' file
```

Use `ver[0]` to include the tag itself, `ver[1]` for just the innerText.

It's based on the condition that all the *root* tags will close.

Comment: wow so complex ... can i just some how to it with shorter simpler method ?
i dont need now the inner text i will pipe with grep

Comment: @user63898 Considering `regex`'s greedy nature and the complexity of this problem, I guess it's not easy...

Comment: very wired that it is so complex , i just what to get text between strings

Comment: @user63898 I guess that's why they suggest you to use xml parser. And my `awk` solution is actually simplified based on the `root tags will close` assumption.

Answer (score 0):

If `Perl` is available, how about:

```
perl -0777 -ne '
    while (m#(<parent>.*</parent>)|(?<=<version>)(.*?)(?=</version>)#sg)
    {print $&, "\n" if $& !~ /(^\$|parent)/}' file.xml
```

although you may still feel it's not simple :).

Explanation:

- `-0777` option tells `perl` to slurp all lines to enable pattern matching on multiple lines.
- The regex matches both patterns: `<parent\>..</parent>` and `<version>..</version>`. The purpose of the former is to skip matching with `<version>` tag within `<parent>` tag.
- Finally it prints the matched substring `$&` excluding the ones which  starts with '$' or contains 'parent'.
- If we could say something like `(?<!<parent>.*)<version>..` as you mention, it would be much simpler.  Unfortunately `variable length lookbehind` is not implemented in `Perl` (and most other languages) as of now.

Answer (score 0):

The question states:

> i can use only native linux tools no installs

and the version of linux being used is described in a comment as:

> yes the standard AWS linux

I have just checked, and [Amazon Linux](https://hub.docker.com/_/amazonlinux/) comes with xmllint preinstalled.

Therefore a solution seems to be:

```
xmllint --xpath "/*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='version']/text()" pom.xml
```